# Using powercfg to duplicate the currently active power scheme

Tags: command-line, batch-file, powercommands

I need to run a batch file, with a series of powercfg commands to duplicate the currently active scheme and rename it.

Manually, I would do something like this at the command prompt.

```
powercfg -getactivescheme
```

This would give me the GUID of currently active scheme.

```
powercfg -duplicatescheme <GUID obtained above> <new GUID>
```

Ideally, I would want to do something like this...

```
powercfg -duplicatescheme -getactivescheme <new GUID>
```

But since this isn't allowed, is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, first you need to pull out the GUID from the output of `powercfg`. This can be done with the `for` command:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%x in ('powercfg -getactivescheme') do echo %%x
```

This will just output the GUID, you can also save it in a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:(" %%x in ('powercfg -getactivescheme') do set guid=%%x
```

You might want to remove extra spaces from this (here I get one space in the front of the line and another two at the end:

```
set guid=%guid: =%
```

Now that you have the GUID, you can put it into your command line above:

```
powercfg -duplicatescheme %guid% <new GUID>
```

You only need to think of a new GUID. I don't know an included commandline program which generates one for you.

NB: The code here (especially the `for` part) assumes that you do this in a batch file. For playing around directly on the commandline, you'd have to use `%x` instead of `%%x` in the `for` commands.